# Formatting picker titles and columns in groups

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I cannot find a way to create a picker where the components are grouped and aligned with titles.  My picker needs to allow multiple types of information to be selected, some of it is composite numbers (i.e. select digits for thousands, hundreds, tens and units).  I have mocked it up here.

[image]

I need a done button, the titles should be centred over the groups and I need a decent space (say 10 pixels) between the titles and the picker data.  I have been doing lots of reading on pickers and understand how to use them, but I am really struggling to find a simple way to format them into groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout is basically a horizontal stack view with `distribution = .fillEqually` and `alignment = .fill`, containing 4 vertical stack views, each with `distribution = .fill` and `alignment = .center`. This is assuming that all the pickers have the same height, and all the texts have the same height.

With this many picker views, it would be a pain to have their data sources and delegates all in one place. I'd write some convenient custom `UIPickerView`s first - one for selecting n digits, and one for selecting Yes/No.

The code may be long, but most of it is boilerplate.

```
class YesNoPicker: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        2
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        row == 0 ? "Yes" : "No"
    }
    
    var enableSelected: Bool {
        self.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
    }
}

class DigitPicker: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var numberOfDigits = 1
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        numberOfDigits
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        10
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        row.description
    }
    
    var selectedNumber: Int {
        var result = 0
        for i in 0..<numberOfDigits {
            result *= 10
            result += self.selectedRow(inComponent: i)
        }
        return result
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Then it's just composing these with stack views. You can tweak the constraints to give appropriate widths and heights for each picker.

```
class MyView: UIView {
    var enabledPicker: YesNoPicker!
    var pressurePicker: DigitPicker!
    var hePicker: DigitPicker!
    var o2Picker: DigitPicker!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        enabledPicker = .init(frame: .zero)
        pressurePicker = .init(frame: .zero)
        pressurePicker.numberOfDigits = 4
        hePicker = .init(frame: .zero)
        o2Picker = .init(frame: .zero)
        let enabledStack = makeVerticalStack(topText: "Enabled", bottomView: enabledPicker)
        let pressureStack = makeVerticalStack(topText: "Press.", bottomView: pressurePicker)
        let heStack = makeVerticalStack(topText: "He", bottomView: hePicker)
        let o2Stack = makeVerticalStack(topText: "O2", bottomView: o2Picker)
        let hStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [enabledStack, pressureStack, heStack, o2Stack])
        hStack.axis = .horizontal
        hStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        hStack.alignment = .fill
        hStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(hStack)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            hStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            hStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            hStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    private func makeVerticalStack(topText: String, bottomView: UIView) -> UIStackView {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = topText
        let vStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label, bottomView])
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.distribution = .fill
        vStack.alignment = .center
        return vStack
    }
}
```

You would access `hePicker.selectedNumber` etc for each picker's selected number.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This looks like what I am looking for, I will play with the grid structure to improve alignment.  Can you advise how to add it into my view?

Comment: Sorry, I built my screen using Interface Builder and have defined UIView and placed it where i would like the above picker to appear.  I am trying to show the picker with myPicker = ContentView() but get a type mismatch error.

Comment: @JimBurke Oh you're using UIKit instead of SwiftUI! I didn't notice that, sorry. I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: @JimBurke See the edit. Just make a new `MyView`, add it as a subview of something, add constraints if necessary.

Comment: Sorry Sweeper, still struggling.  I've defined a @IBOutlet weak var blendGasPicker: UIView! in my ViewController and assign your picker to it as blendGasPicker.addSubview(GasPickerView()) [note I've renamed MyView as GasPickerView].  Really struggling to see what I am doing wrong.  Can I share code.  Your approach will really help.

Comment: @JimBurke I’m sorry, but I’m not going to give you a step by step tutorial on how to use a custom `UIView`. You should be able to just set `GasPickerView` as the class of the view you have in the storyboard, in the identity inspector. Please do some research yourself, and if you are still struggling, post a new question and include a [mcve] of your attempt.